# Simple Search Ruby Limitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I have implemented a Simple Search in Ruby on Rails under the following guidance of the following tutorial from [Koren Leslie Cohen](http://www.korenlc.com/creating-a-simple-search-in-rails-4/). The search works fine **if** you are present in the index.html.erb view already. If you are in a show.html.erb view for example the search fails to work, it is merely appending the search to the end of the current views URL.

**Example:**
http://localhost:3000/post/Hello%20World?utf8=✓&search=first

What does work is the following.

**Example:** 
http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=✓&search=hello

The question is how can I get the simple search to redirect to say the index.html.erb page and then apply the relevant search filter to that view? Alternatively is there a better way that I could implement this?

---

Below is the code references

**_header.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path(), :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts", class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  # The following arranges for pagination on the index page
  @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  elsif params[:category_groups_id]
    @posts = Post.where(:category_groups_id => params[:category_groups_id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  else
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
end
```

**post.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
  where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Comment: Try this for your form tag: `<%= form_tag("/posts", :method => "get") do %>`

Comment: Example 1 is appending '/Hello%20World' . from where it is coming? you are tying it / searching it? this example is not working fine? right?

Comment: @AwaisShafqat when I am in a post's show.html.erb and I try to search it appends the search query to the end of the URL.

Comment: @TheF it still appends the search query to the end of the URL, it doesn't redirect to the index.html.erb to which I would like the search criteria filter applied.

Comment: ok. replace 'posts_path( )' with 'posts_path'. its not function. secondly replace 'params[:search]' with ' ' empty string or nil and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

For a different setup do this:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get 'search' as 'posts#index'
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(search_path) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, placeholder: "Search Posts", class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

This should be enough to make your search forms action point to `/posts?search=xyz`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a rookie error on my part, had the **form_tag** situated in a **form**.

Appreciate the feedback, it forced me to go through all of the code with a fine tooth comb.